# How do I send email from linux terminal, with contents of multiple files as the mail-body?

Tags: linux, email

I am aware that I can use the following command from my linux terminal to send an email:

```
sendmail user@example.com < file1.text
```

This command will basically send the contents of the *file1.text* as mail body.
But how can I add contents of multiple files inside mail body using the same command?

I tried the following which obviously did not work:

```
sendmail user@example.com < file1.text,file2.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `cat` command. `cat` is short for "concatenate"; it will concatenate all the files given on the command line. Then pipe the output to sendmail:

```
cat file1.text file2.text | sendmail user@example.com
```